# libgdx для html

Tags: java, libgdx

Пишу игру на `libgdx 0.9.9`. Запускаю на `desktop` и `android`. Работает.

Пытаюсь скомпилировать по `html`. Не работает.

В начале выводит:

```
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors. 
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/home/artem/java_project/project/test_0.0.9/magicballs-html/../magicballs/src/com/magicballs/game/Magicballs.java'
[ERROR] Line 13: No source code is available for type screan_level_strategy.ScreenManager; did you forget to inherit a required module? 
[ERROR] Line 14: No source code is available for type screan_level_strategy.CustomScreen; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

В конце кода:

```
Adding '1' new generated units Validating units:
   Warnings in '/tmp/gwt-codeserver-8213221912207040889.tmp/com.magicballs.game.GwtDefinition/compile-1/gen/com/badlogic/gwtref/client/IReflectionCacheGenerated.java'
      See snapshot: /tmp/com.badlogic.gwtref.client.IReflectionCacheGenerated2668413195780393369.java 
Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass. 
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.

[ERROR] Compiler returned false 

  com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:128) 
  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.ModuleState.<init>(ModuleState.java:58) 
  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.makeModules(CodeServer.java:120) 
  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:95) 
  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:71) 
  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:49)
```

Для `html` делаю, как написано в [статье](http://www.libgdx.ru/2013/09/gwt-super-dev-mode.html).

Использую менеджер экранов.

Взял [здесь](https://github.com/miroshn/CartoonRaider/blob/6c6702e1cba15e239fcd45701e54f2e4d49b5366/core/src/ru/miroshn/cartoon_raider/screens/ScreenManager.java).

Скажите, что я делаю не так? Дайте совет.